# Can I control the flashlight without using android.hardware.Camera?

Tags: android, camera, zxing, flashlight

The use of front light option with `zxing1.6` barcode scanner does not work on my Nexus One. I need to be able to use the flashlight in my app, but you can't have two instances of the camera running. Is there a way to use the flashlight without accessing the camera? Or can I somehow access a camera that is already in use?

I am using the Google `IntentIntegrator.java` patch to be able to scan barcodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is "no"; the front LED is controlled as a flash mode, which is a property of the camera. It is mode "torch". And no two apps can't open the camera at the same time.

(A longer answer is that there used to be a hidden API for this, which is what Barcode Scanner tries to access, but it doesn't work on almost any device anymore. You can dig into the source code to see `FlashlightManager`.)

Since Android 2.x there is this proper API for turning on the light, and the beta of the next version of Barcode Scanner does use it. You can try it [here](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/detail?name=BarcodeScanner-debug.apk).

Comment: @SeanOwen : Can we turn on the flashlight using the front camera instance parameters as well?