# can I manipulate the flashlight of the mobile without asking user for camera permissions?

Tags: android, android-camera, flashlight

[Can I control the flashlight without using android.hardware.Camera?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024087/can-i-control-the-flashlight-without-using-android-hardware-camera)
I found this answer. Is the answer still "no", or, is there a way to do it. I currently work on windows android studio

Comment: The answer is still the same... You cant.

Comment: Check this link for [Android M Camera API Overview](https://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html#camera). Not Sure about the permisisons.

Comment: Actually, I think in the next release (Android M) it will be possible. But yeah... if you want to target older api, we must ask for permission.

Comment: http://www.androidauthority.com/best-android-flashlight-apps-with-no-extra-permissions-568939/
how are they doing this?